# Where is the source code that implements the driver for /dev/ttyS0 serial port in Red Hat?

Tags: redhat, serial

I am trying to debug a problem with a device attached to /dev/ttyS0 on a workstation running RHEL 5.  Using my relatively basic Linux knowledge, I can not seem to figure out where to look for the source code for the serial port driver.  Where is it and what is it called?

Comment: Perhaps you could post another question about the actual problem.  You'll need to decide whether the appropriate place for the question is Server Fault or Super User (or, if it's programming related, Stack Overflow). Serial problems are often a matter of correct cabling or parameter configuration. Digging in the source is less often necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the RHEL5 package, you can download the kernel source RPM [here](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/).  If you want the kernel source from the primary distribution, you can get it from [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/).

Depending on the particular driver or part of the kernel you want to look at, it may be in the `linux/drivers/serial` directory.